# unable to login with leetcode cookie in vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am unable to login to leetcode when using the VS code extension

keep getting the below error :
let s = args.map(x => x.toString()).join(' ');

[image]

is there a new way to login instead of using cookies ?

VS code : v 1.87
Node : v21.7.1

tried most of the solutions given online but no luck , not sure if something changed

Comment: Copy your error message here instead of using screenshot please